# Table Padding Top

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know how to put the content of the first `td` to the top of `td`, in this case? I had tried padding, margin, and anything else, but it doesn't work.

```html
  <table>
    <tr>
    <td>AuthRequest</td>
    <td>when specifying an account, one of <password> or <preauth> must be specified. See preauth.txt for a discussion of preauth.
    An authToken can be passed instead of account/password/preauth to validate an existing auth token. If {verifyAccount}="1", <account> is required and the account in the auth token is compared to the named account.
    Mismatch results in auth failure. An external app that relies on ZCS for user identification can use this to test if the auth token provided by the user belongs to that user. If {verifyAccount}="0" (default), only the auth token is verified and any <account> element specified is ignored. </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

[image]

Comment: css table td:first-child { vertical-align: top;}

Comment: By the way, the `<password>` and the `<preauth>` doesn't appear on the snippet, nor on the picture.  To make it appear, change `<` to `&lt;`, and `>` to `&gt;`.  That would be, `&lt;password&gt;` and `&lt;preauth&gt;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go! Use the `vertical-align` property.

```html
  <table>
    <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align:top">AuthRequest</td>
    <td>when specifying an account, one of <password> or <preauth> must be specified. See preauth.txt for a discussion of preauth.
    An authToken can be passed instead of account/password/preauth to validate an existing auth token. If {verifyAccount}="1", <account> is required and the account in the auth token is compared to the named account.
    Mismatch results in auth failure. An external app that relies on ZCS for user identification can use this to test if the auth token provided by the user belongs to that user. If {verifyAccount}="0" (default), only the auth token is verified and any <account> element specified is ignored. </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: No problem! Glad you got it sorted out. Please mark as accepted when you get the chance to.

Comment: @TramHongAnh If you think this had solved your problem, mark it as accepted, by clicking the gray checkbox below the downvote button.  This answer is accepted, when the checkbox is shown in green color.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking keep it in two columns then use Felix's code and if you are looking to put it above the first td then you can put it in a row.

```html
 <table>
    <tr>
    <td>AuthRequest</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>when specifying an account, one of <password> or <preauth> must be specified. See preauth.txt for a discussion of preauth.
    An authToken can be passed instead of account/password/preauth to validate an existing auth token. If {verifyAccount}="1", <account> is required and the account in the auth token is compared to the named account.
    Mismatch results in auth failure. An external app that relies on ZCS for user identification can use this to test if the auth token provided by the user belongs to that user. If {verifyAccount}="0" (default), only the auth token is verified and any <account> element specified is ignored. </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: that was a prematured click. I had already commented the answer